# Editing repeating table INfoPath Form in form library?

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I created repeating table and I added two fields in it.while publishing its not giving me option to edit those properties in my document library...when we generally publish we get the option to edit those properties in document library but its disable while creating repeating table any suggestions how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Check the box to enable editing in SP during your form publish.